# Semantic-UI: How to limit card content block so it doesn’t push extra content

Tags: css, grid-layout, semantic-ui

I'm trying to make a full page grid using Semantic-UI grid and cards.

Here's what I got: http://codepen.io/emzero/pen/Vjrrab?editors=1100

See how the `extra content` (yellow) gets pushed down and out of the card when the screen size is not big enough? 
I'd like the `extra content` to be always visible at the bottom of the card and just trim the `body` content if it doesn't fit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a matter of making the text of the body also `display: flex`.

Here's the resulting version: http://codepen.io/emzero/pen/rLGAzy